# Method 'Range" of object'_Global" failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have taken a Excel document we use at work and modified it for a separate task that has developed.

I was told that as long as column E remained a date then the "Show Only Most Recent Issuance" macro should still run.

However I am receiving the above Run Time Error and when I select debug I am unsure what to change in order to fix said error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Issuance" & Chr(10) & "Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
    , Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

The changes I made were only to the column titles and also to the data validation ranges for columns that should not be included in the macro.

Thanks.

Comment: did you remove any column titles, or did you change column E's name away from "Issuance"?

Comment: Yes I changed column E's name to Action Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you changed the column title in column E. Before it looks like it was "Issuance Date" with a line break in-between Issuance and Date.

If you did change that column title you either need to change it back or update the macro to use the new name. The column name should go between the brackets, after "Table1".

Comment: That is exactly what I changed.  So based on your answer I went into the Macro and changed "Issuance" to "Action" (the new title) and now have a new syntax error.          , Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

Comment: well you need to note the full column name the code is looking for: "Table1[Issuance" & Chr(10) & "Date]". In that, Chr(10) is about equivalent to the Enter key on the keyboard. So if the column is just named "Action Date" without a newline then it now should be: "Table1[Action Date]"

Comment: I named the column with a line break so it is "Action Alt-Enter Date"  Is that correct??  I am sorry to be a pest, but I am totally new to the Macro side of Excel and I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Figured out the problem!!  I was trying to edit the macro within the debug and so my changes were not actually taking.  Now that I opened the macro inside the spreadsheet it is working.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @LeahFord - glad to help, if this arcane vba knowledge is going to stick in my brain it might as well help someone else